# Does L.mapbox.featureLayer() support LineString?

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I have followed mapbox.js documentation to implement `geojson` `LineString` over my map without success.

Does `L.mapbox.featureLayer()` support `LineString`?

Here is my code:

```
var myMarkers_sende = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
.addTo(map);
myMarkers_sende.loadURL('myurl/map_sende.geojson');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `L.mapbox.featureLayer` does support the `LineString` geometry type. This is a problem somewhere else: enabling [browser debugging](http://debugbrowser.com) might point out an issue in Javascript, or if you can provide more complete code & data, we could help debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Debugging does not seem to point out specific error in code. The complete page is available [here](http://www.mapatraslasierra.com.ar/index_test.html)

Comment: Your LineString data is invalid. Look at the GeoJSON - coordinates look like `304213.7949419716, 6463774.218852242`: these need to be valid longitude and latitude values, which means these numbers are wildly out or range.

Comment: Thanks. The file is a "save as GeoJson" of a shape file in qgis. I will try something else or may be reprojet in qgis. Is it possible to have a Satellite Bing Layer in geojson.io? How?

Comment: You'll need to reproject to EPSG:4326 in QGIS. No, geojson.io doesn't/won't support Bing, since it would be legally risky for anyone to draw anything on Bing imagery.

Comment: Thanks to you I fixed it reprojecting to EPSG:4326. I tried to styled the lines with _style_ feature explain [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Geojson_CSS) without success. Are the Geojson sanitize? Or do I should I try to style them using the _class_ feature?

Comment: @Inclanfunk please open other questions for that